# How to fetch App Store reviews even though they don't have text?

Tags: mobile, app-store, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

I'm using App Store Connect API and I found
[List All Customer Reviews for an App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_customer_reviews_for_an_app), however, it only returns reviews that have text.

Is there a way to get all new reviews?
Or just get some aggregate? e.g. 2600 total reviews and then distribution of it by star.

Even by scraping them from somewhere?